# has_many through: four layers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

How do you manage a four-layer model connection?

So I have Group, which has many Categories, which has many Exams, which as many Topics.

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :categories
   has_many :exams, through: :categories
   #has_many :topics, through :exams
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
  has_many :exams
end

class Exam < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :topics
  has_one :group, through: :category
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :topics
end

class Topic < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :exam
  has_one :category, through: :exam
  #has_one :group, through :category
end
```

How do I accurately connect Group through to Topic, given the two tables in the middle?

(Edited for clarity)

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is... are you having a particular problem?

Comment: How do I connect topic to group?

Comment: What happens when you do the thing you have commented out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I missing? Or is it just ridiculous to have four layers?

Not ridiculous. Just provide `has_many` `through` association as usual:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categories
  has_many :exams, through: :categories
  has_many :topics, through: :exams
end
```

That will generate an SQL, something like:

```
SELECT  "topics".* FROM "topics" INNER JOIN "exams" ON "topics"."exam_id" = "exams"."id" INNER JOIN "categories" ON "exams"."category_id" = "categories"."id" WHERE "categories"."group_id" = ?
```